# How do I update my gcc, Sudo Apt Update Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to update the newest version of gcc on my linux and I am running into an error with the Sudo Apt Update code. I'm new to coding, can anyone advise? Also, when I do try to update it says my gcc is up to date. It is version 5.4.0 which does not seem to be the newest one. Thanks!

(base) bsilagy@ENS12372 ~ $ sudo apt update                                                                                                                    W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: In the stuff you quoted above, I cannot find the "computer is telling me that it is" part.

Comment: Not that this answers your question, but what was wrong with the version you had?  You said you are new to coding.. I have to seriously doubt that you needed whatever features have been added since the last release.

Comment: You will find (especially with Linux).. older versions of things are often more stable (to include package management of said thing).. I myself never upgrade unless I need something and or there is some sort of security flaw that needed to be patched.

Comment: I am a grad assistant and my post doc has created a package that requires a newer version of c++. So yes, I needed to update because I couldn't install his package successfully without. I apologize if my question was obscure. I tried posting the whole code error, but stack overflow said there were more than 10 links so I couldn't post.  I did get it figured out though, sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-9 g++-9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9